# How to mock inputRef of a textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

My UI contains a textfield, a button and the text result.

When enter a string, then click REMOVE button, the text result doesn't contain 'dog'

```
    class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: '',
    };
  };

  handleConvertString = (event) => {
    let str = this.inputRef.value;
    this.setState({
      text: str.replace(/dog/gi, ''),
    })
  };
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <TextField
          label="the string what you want to remove 'dog' "
          style={{ margin: 8 }}
          fullWidth
          margin="normal"
          ref="myField"
          inputRef={ref => { this.inputRef = ref; }}
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
        />
        <div style={styleDivButton}>
          <Button className={classes.button} onClick={this.handleConvertString}>Remove</Button>
        </div>
        <p>{'"' + this.state.text + '"'}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

How to mock `this.inputRef.value`

```
it('test handler handleRemove', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Exercise1 />);
  //how to mock this.inputRef.value = "dog is a loyal pet"

  wrapper.instance().handleConvertString();
  expect(wrapper.state('text')).toBe(" is a loyal pet");
});
```

Comment: You *shouldn't* mock the inputRef, that's an internal implementation detail. You shouldn't be calling methods on the component either, for the same reason. I'd also recommend using mount wherever possible. Then you can: simulate the input; simulate the click; re-render the component; and assert on the updated DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I mock by assign directly to `wrapper`. The test is passed. But I'm not sure this is a correct approach

```
it('test handler handleRemove', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Exercise1 />);
  wrapper.instance().inputRef = {value: "dog is a loyal pet"} //mock this.inputRef.value = "dog is a loyal pet"

  wrapper.instance().handleConvertString();
  expect(wrapper.state('text')).toBe(" is a loyal pet");
});
```

Comment: This is a test of *implementation*, not behaviour. It's a very fragile test that doesn't tell you whether the component will actually work in real life.

Comment: in my opinion mocking `ref` in this way is fine(although I'd prefer `React.createRef()` alternative to ref-callback). but calling `wrapper.instance().handleConvertString()` is definitely about testing implementation. So it'd better replaced with `wrapper.find(Button).props().onClick()`